# Implement like/unlike function in ionic 2 with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I am trying to implement user like/unlike function in ionic 2. The idea is simply to click the like button to toggle like/unlike status.

```
likeItem(itemId) {
let objRef = this.af.database.object('userItemCollection/'+this.userId+'/items/'+itemId);
objRef.subscribe(snapshot => {
  if(snapshot.$value) {
    objRef.remove();
  } else {
    objRef.set(true);
  }
});
}
```

However, once I click the like button and trigger the function, I can see in the Firebase console, it adds many records to the database. I am not sure where I go wrong.

Comment: Hi William. Did my answer help you - or did you need more information?

Comment: yes, it works, thanks for your help. I was previously using a workaround (click to increase the like count, and check if the count % 2 == 0 to mimic boolean operation), your solution is more proper and fits my original purpose. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the Observable take method::

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take'

likeItem(itemId) {
    let objRef = this.af.database.object('/item/itemId', { preserveSnapshot: true })
    objRef.take(1)
    .subscribe(snapshot => objRef.set({like: !snapshot.val().like}))
}
```

I hope this solves your question :)